# Windows 7 to XP logon issues

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I just got a new computer with Win7.  I have other computers with XP.

Most of the computers have file and print sharing turned on and guest account active. On these computers, I can access shared folders either from the command line (e.g,. dir //name/folder) or from explorer.

One of the XP machines had the guest account turned off.  I first tried logging in with my Win7 credentials, which failed.  I then turned on the guest account, made sure I was sharing some folders and they didn't have permissions issues, and tried again from the Win7 machine.  It keeps asking me for username/password.

All machines are on my local network.  Net view lists them all. The problem machine shows the correct time.

I then tried running gpresult on the problem machine and another machine. The problem had no entries under "the computer is part of the following security groups." Another machine listed a few accounts.

What should I do to logon to this XP computer?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the logon problem (case sensitive):

```
net user guest /active:yes 
ntrights +r SeNetworkLogonRight -u Guest 
ntrights -r SeDenyNetworkLogonRight -u Guest
```